# ionic 3 typescript : passing object between pages by value

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, return-by-value

I'm working on an Ionic 3 Application and I have a page which list items if we click on an item it goes to page item update

The page item update contains an update button, but when I updated some input and I return back without clicking on the update button, I found the item already updated

So I think that the problem was that I'm passing the item by reference:

Code:

***items page template (item = recipe here) : recipes.html***

```
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" [navPush]="recipePage" [navParams]="recipe">
      <h2>{{recipe.title}}</h2>
      <p>{{recipe.difficulty}}</p>
  </button>
```

***item details page component: recipe.ts***

```
  ionViewDidLoad(){

      this.recipe = this.navParams.data ;

  }
```

Question how can I pass the recipe with value and not with reference please ?

Comment: In this case you should create copy of the object and on save update the real reference

Comment: can you post code of your update item page .ts file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kriss said you should create a deep copy of your object. Something like this:

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.originalRecipe = this.navParams.data ;
    this.recipe =  Object.assign({}, this.originalRecipe);
  };

  update(){
    this.originalRecipe = this.recipe;
  };
```

Comment: The problem that when the object contains an array field and we use this clone method, the contained array will stay passed by reference, this was my problem.

Comment: if your object contains arrays the easiest way to loose all reference  is `this.recipe  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.originalRecipe))`